# How to fixed center point when pinching the map on IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I tried to use :

```
mapView.centerCoordinate = mycenterCoordinate!
```

in `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` event handler, but it only fixed the center point but not resizing the map when I pitch the map. Any Idea how I can cope with that?

Comment: Please share if you found out the answer

Comment: @Dhariwal_Kuldeep you need to adjust the zoom level yourself every time the pinch gesture occurs